# optimal k for knn algorithm in item based recommendation system using cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, algorithms, k-nearest-neighbour, recommender-system

I'm trying to make a recommendation system in my Graduation project app using k-nearest neighbor algorithm.

I make an item recommendation system to recommend products to the active user based on products rating. my dataset is a matrix filled from the database, the columns represent the system's users, and the rows represent the products in the system, and the matrix filled with the rating values for each product from each user. as the following example

[image: dataset example]

but in my case there is products not movies.

there is now 17 products(rows) and 12 users (columns). but I want an accurate general way to find k .

I used $k=\sqrt{n}/2$ as an equation to find a good k value (n represents the number of products in the application). but I want more accurate way to find the k value, someone give me an advice to use k-fold cross-validation, after searching, I understood how to use cross-validation for classification.
Can anyone explain to me how to use it in Recommendation systems?

Comment: Hi ror roro, can you explain why the solution for $k$ that you mentioned is not satisfying to you?

Comment: Hi @Fato39, it's not like that I'm not satisfied, but because I used this algorithm in my graduation project, I should use a more accurate way